# Firebase Facebook login android

Tags: android, firebase, facebook, kotlin, facebook-login

I'm using Firebase Facebook login and it is working fine if the Facebook app is installed. when i try to the use Facebook login without the App, it redirects to the Facebook login Webpage, and when i login and press continue. it is not redirecting to my Application.

```
fbLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager,object: FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
            override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
                handleFacebookAccessToken(result!!.accessToken,activity,mAuth,binding)
            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
                Toast.makeText(activity,error!!.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                Log.w("FB", "cancelled")
            }

        })
```

I'm using this above callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `fbLogin` is  `LoginManager.getInstance()`, if not then you should change it to that.

Then your callback will be :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(
     callbackManager,
     object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
         override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
             val token = result?.accessToken
                    
             // This is used to get user info.
             val request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(token) { `object`, _ ->
             try {
                 val name = `object`.getString("name")
                 val email = `object`.getString("email")

                 showLoginDialog(name = name, email = email,token = token?.token)
             }catch (ex: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, ex.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
             }
           }

           val bundle = Bundle()
           bundle.putString("fields", "id,name,email")
           request.parameters = bundle
                    request.executeAsync()
         }

         override fun onCancel() {
             Toast.makeText(activity, "Login cancelled !!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
         }

         override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
             Toast.makeText(activity, error?.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
         }

 })
```

In `onActivityResult()` : This will be used to redirect to your `Application`.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Comment: fbLogin is the facebook login button, should i just use LoginManager.getInstance() there?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: is it onActivityResult() in fragments too?

Comment: if you calling the login in a fragment then you will have update the onactivityresult function in that too.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the solution. the Facebook callback was not getting triggered as i had (android:noHistory="true") in the activity properties at the Manifest.